# Oracle Apex Set collection member to null upon Undo change

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a Page with Interactive grid data beings stored in collection for validation.

```
Declare
Begin
cursor crec is select emp_id, dept_id, bonus from employees;
apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection('COLL1');
For c in crec
LOOP
apex_collection.add_member(p_collection_name => 'COLL1',p_c001=>c.emp_id,p_c002=> c.dept_id, p_c003 => c.bonus);
END LOOP;
end;
```

EMP_ID is being stored in page item P1_EMP_ID.

I have 2 processes for this grid, one to update and the other to undo changes.
Update is using apex_collection.update_member with sequence to update the values.

Before using collections, when it was a simple grid I had
:P1_BONUS := null.

So on click of Undo button bonus would get set to null.
But in collections, i see BONUS, i.e. c003 is not set to null.

How can i set the collection value to null as well?